# Why does document.writeln("a" || "b") print "a" instead of "true"?

Tags: javascript

Why does `document.writeln("a" || "b")` print `a` instead of `true`?

`document.writeln("a" && "b")` prints `b`

`document.writeln(1==1 && 1!=1)` prints `false`

`document.writeln(1!=1 && 'b')` prints `false`

`document.writeln(1==1 && 'b')` prints `b`

Does it evaluate the inner portion and return the last value for `&&`, and the first true value for `||`?

Comment: Why would it print true? "a" is a non blank, defined string so it is truthy and hence it is returned to the method. Also 1==1 will be evaluated, better to use 1===1 which will not cast the ints to strings

Comment: I like this behaviour, and to be honest, didn't even consider it beforehand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`||` and `&&` don't always return booleans. `||` evaluates the first argument. If it would evaluate to true, it returns that argument. Otherwise, it returns the second argument (unconditionally).

`&&` evaluates the first argument. If it would evaluate to true, it returns the second argument (unconditionally). Otherwise it returns the first argument.

This allows you to do some neat things like:

```
function foo(optionalVar) {
    var x = optionalVar || 4; 
}
foo(10); //uses 10, since it is passed in;
foo(); //uses 4, the default value, since optionalVar=undefined, which is false
```

Comment: i first saw this in a bit of code like the example you provided.

Answer (score 2):

Its order of operations and truth tables.

```
If(a OR b) : if a is true than the whole statement is true
If(a AND b): if a is true, doesnt mean that the statement is true, 
             but if b is true as well than the statement is true
|| is the same as OR
&& is the same as AND
```

*UPDATE*
So in functional programming it returns the **1st** `true` value. a string is considered `true` therefore it would return the string.
[Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) pointed out: 
The empty string, it should be noted, is **not** `true`. (Which is to say, of course, that it's `false`)

Comment: The empty string, it should be noted, is **not** `true`.  (Which is to say, of course, that it's `false`.)

Comment: changed my answer to better reflect